# Set a cookie to display a one time modal pop up without calling any JavaScript libraries - native JavaScript/DOM API only

Tags: javascript, cookies

I would like first time visitors to my site to see a "welcome" modal pop up which does not render more than once a year, unless they delete their browsing data.

For the sake of performance (and also the learning exercise), I do not want to call any external JavaScript libraries.

My code, below, sets a cookie with an expiry date and a Boolean value for whether the user has visited before to true, and then recalls that cookie to hide the modal div if the value is already true.

I would be grateful if the community would help me understand the problem with my JavaScript. Above all, Jsfiddle runs it differently to the local version although the code is the same, and I am totally confused as to why.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// set a cookie on the load event, which expires after a year

window.onload = function() {
  var expiryTime = new Date();
  expiryTime.setFullYear(expiryTime.getFullYear() + 1);
document.cookie = "visited=true; expires=" + expiryTime.toUTCString() + ";";
}

// function to hide the modal div

function hideModal() {
  document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
}

// read the cookie and hide the modal div if the value of visitedKey is true

function inspectCookie() {
  var visitedKey = "visited=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(visitedKey) == true) {
      hideModal()
    }
  }
}

// run the cookie checking function as soon as the parser hits it - rather than waiting for the whole page to render then hiding the modal div

inspectCookie();

</script>

<style type="text/css">

#modal,
h3 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

#modal {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 60%;
  padding: 5%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #644;
}

h3 {
  z-index: 0;
}

</style>

<div id="modal">

  <h1>
     Welcome!
  </h1>

  <p>
    This is a modal pop up which should only appear on the user's first visit!  
  </p>

  <a href="#" onclick="hideModal()">close</a>

</div>

<h3>This is the content of the page.</h3>
```

The jsfiddle I have been working with is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zLbcwpdv/34/

Comment: What is the difference? and what exactly is not working?

Comment: The jsFiddle for some reason don't see the `hideModal` function, check this http://jsfiddle.net/zLbcwpdv/39/

Comment: The difference between Jsfiddle and the local version is that Jsfiddle doesn't run the hideModal() function. The console doesn't give me any insights - it seems to ignore it.

Comment: The problem is that neither the local version nor the Jsfiddle version actually hide the div when the value is already set to true.

Comment: Check this updated fiddle, you had several issues there, indexOf() returns -1 if not found and the index number of found and not a boolean value, also you missed the name of the key (its visited and not visited=). http://jsfiddle.net/zLbcwpdv/40/

Comment: Thank you for fixing up the hideModal() issue!!

The thing I still don't get is why the modal div still renders each time I refresh?

Comment: Also note that the fiddle JS is set to start on load, while you attach the onload event on load, so your onload event won't fire because it was set after onload already run. this fiddle run when the dom is loaded but before onload function http://jsfiddle.net/zLbcwpdv/45/

Comment: Thank you @Art3mix - I think you have solved it. If you would like to turn this into an answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLbcwpdv/45)

```
// set a cookie on the load event, which expires after a year

window.onload = function() {
  var expiryTime = new Date();
  expiryTime.setFullYear(expiryTime.getFullYear() + 1);
  document.cookie = "visited=true; expires=" + expiryTime.toUTCString() + ";";
  console.log(document.cookie);
}

// function to hide the modal div

window.hideModal = function () {
  document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "none";
}

// read the cookie and hide the modal div if the value of visitedKey is true

function inspectCookie() {
  var visitedKey = "visited";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(visitedKey) !== -1) {
      window.hideModal()
    }
  }
}

// run the cookie checking function as soon as the parser hits it - rather than waiting for the whole page to render then hiding the modal div

inspectCookie();
```

**Issues**

1. Your key was `visited=` while the key should be `visited`;
2. indexOf() return the index of the found value, and -1 if the value was not found, it doesn't reutnr a boolean, so to check if it was found, you need to compare it to -1 (-1 if not found, other number of found).
3. You set your cookie on the onload event, but in the fiddle you override the onload function **after** the onload was already fired, so the onload function you set wasn't running because the load event already run before you override the onload function.

You should really learn more about events and JS functions you use.

Comment: Thank you. I will learn more about events and functions I am using.